# Xcode UI Testing - typing text with typeText() method and autocorrection

Tags: uitextfield, ios9, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I've got a test like below:

```
let navnTextField = app.textFields["First Name"]
let name = "Henrik"
navnTextField.tap()
navnTextField.typeText("Henrik")
XCTAssertEqual(navnTextField.value as? String, name)
```

Problem is that by default my `iPhone Simulator` has got Polish keyboard because of the system settings and "Henrik" is automatically changed into "ha" by autocorrect.

Simple solution is to remove Polish keyboard from the `iOS Settings`. This solution however is not solving the problem because `iPhone Simulator` can be reset and then test will fail again.

Is there any way to setup autocorrect before test case or other way to input text to text field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a workaround to use UIPasteboard to provide input text:

```
let navnTextField = app.textFields["First name"]
navnTextField.tap()
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Henrik"
navnTextField.doubleTap()
app.menuItems.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
XCTAssertEqual(navnTextField.value as? String, name)
```

You can check [link with description as a workaround for secure input in GM](https://rnorth.org/11/automated-ui-testing-in-xcode-7?utm_content=buffer19f8b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

**Edit**

For better readability instead `app.menuItems.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()`
you can do `app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()`.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a small extension on XCUIElement to accomplish this

```
extension XCUIElement {
    // The following is a workaround for inputting text in the 
    //simulator when the keyboard is hidden
    func setText(text: String, application: XCUIApplication) {
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = text
        doubleTap()
        application.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
    }
}
```

It can be used like this

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let enterNameTextField =  app.otherElements.textFields["Enter Name"]
enterNameTextField.tap()
enterNameTextField.setText("John Doe", app)
```

- Credit goes to @Apan for the implementation

Comment: doubleTap() could be a problem if text is already in this textfield, cause ti will select part of text

Comment: This works for me only if I insert arbitrary delays between the tap, doubleTap, and paste. I guess it might be a performance thing? My simulator is running too slowly to keep up with all of the taps?

Answer (score 19):

Currently using Swift 4 on Xcode 10 
you can now use `typeText(String)` like this

    `let app = XCUIApplication()
    let usernameTextField = app.textFields["Username"]
    usernameTextField.typeText("Caseyp")`

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer considering the state of the IDE as of Xcode 11.....

Comment: for Xcode 13.3.1, we have to focus on the field, before we execute `typeTest`. Thus add `usernameTextField.tap()` before the last line.

Answer (score 3):

For swift v3 need use new sintax (answer by @mike):

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func setText(text: String?, application: XCUIApplication) {
        tap()
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text
        doubleTap()
        application.menuItems.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let enterNameTextField =  app.otherElements.textFields["Enter Name"]
enterNameTextField.tap()
enterNameTextField.setText(text: "John Doe", application: app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tweaked:

1. so extension is on application which makes a bit more sense to me
2. the existing field contents are emptied

code:

```
extension XCUIApplication {
      // The following is a workaround for inputting text in the
      //simulator when the keyboard is hidden
      func setText(_ text: String, on element: XCUIElement?) {
        if let element = element {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text
        element.doubleTap()
        self.menuItems["Select All"].tap()
        self.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
        }
      }
    }
```

Run with:

```
self.app?.setText("Lo", on: self.app?.textFields.firstMatch)
```